# symfony + knp_snappy : failed to load and blocked access errors

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, symfony5, knp-snappy

I have a malfunction with Symfony 5.4 and knp_snappy (1.9) with wkhtmltopdf (12.6). The application uses Webpack-Encore (1.16). This is error in not present in my development environment (ISO with prod).

For 2 weeks, when I try to generate a PDF, there is an error that occurs on the environment where the application was deployed:

```
snappy.ERROR: An error happened while generating "/tmp/knp_snappy641b08fd3d2325.77113643.pdf". {"command":"xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy641b08fd3d1788.78365795.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy641b08fd3d2325.77113643.pdf'","status":1,"stdout":"","stderr":"QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-peir'\nLoading page (1/2)\n[>                                                           ] 0%\r[=====================>                                      ] 35%\rWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/1.329d65bc.css\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/app.b69d4246.css\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/images/urne.png\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/images/logos_metiers/marianne/marianne.png\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/js/popper.js\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/runtime.d94b3b43.js\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/0.8ecf1583.js\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/1.0807a62f.js\nWarning: Blocked access to file /PEIR/www/app/public/build/app.bffbb929.js\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\nWarning: Blocked access to file \nError: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol \"about\" is unknown\n[============================================================] 100%\rPrinting pages (2/2)                                               \n[>                                                           ] \rDone                                                           \nExit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError\n"} []
```

This is my knp_snappy file configuration:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled: true
        binary: '%env(WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH)%'
        options:
            enable-local-file-access: true
    image:
        enabled: true
        binary: '%env(WKHTMLTOIMAGE_PATH)%'
        options:
            enable-local-file-access: true
```

Do you have an idea to solve this?

Comment: `Failed to load about:blank` sounds strange

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have try to check if it is a permission problem with wkhtmltopdf (read, write, execute) and I have added "enable-local-file-access" in knp snappy file configuration (it was not present before). The error appeared as a result of upgrading to version 12.6 of kwhtmltopdf (before, it was 12.5 version).